# MySQL - Many to Many relationship - tables

Tags: mysql

In a MySQL database, We have three tables: 'Answers', 'Items' and 'AnswerItems' that links between the first two tables.

Answers Table

AnswerID

(and other columns)

===================

Items Table

ItemID

(and other columns)

==================

AnswerItems Table

AnswerID

ItemID

===============

now, we want to get answers that have certain items (not more or less)

we tried this (assuming we are searching for answers having items with IDs: FirstItemID and SecondItemID)

```
select AnswerID
from AnswerItems
where ItemID in (FirstItemID,SecondItemID) 
group by AnswerID
having COUNT(distinct ItemID) = 2
```

this query also returns answers that have other items with the selected two items above

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9124/3

Comment: could you post sqlfiddle for this?

Comment: Does it work ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9124/4

Comment: In your having you have to proof `DISTINCT ItemId` or you remove te `DISTINCT` if you would use AnswerID. `Distinct` make the result unique. In your case you get always a count of 1

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d856b/1 , I added a third row to AnswersItems where AnswerId=1 and ItemID = 3-- the query still returns answer #1 (answer #1 now have items 1+2+3), we need answers that have items 1+2 only

Comment: I see, in this case the following should do the trick http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d856b/3, let me know if this helps I will add this as answer !

Comment: @lopo Sorry, I don't understand ,, but the query in the question works with answers having items 1 and 2 (+ other items)

Comment: Try this query

`select 
  AnswerID,
  COUNT(distinct AnswerID),
  COUNT(distinct ItemID)
from AnswerItems
where ItemID in (1,2) 
group by AnswerID`

There you can see, if you count distinct (means unique count), then the having in your example is always false. You group by AnswerID and count unique AnswerID the count is always 1.

Comment: OOOPS, sorry, it's having COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) = 2 ,, not having COUNT(DISTINCT AnswerID) = 2 - I will edit the question

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty it works, add it as answer, it's an alternative idea to InoS Heo answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find AnswerID has Only ItemID 1 and 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM AnswerItems t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AnswerID
    FROM AnswerItems
    WHERE ItemID in (1, 2)
    GROUP BY AnswerID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) = 2
) t2 ON t1.AnswerID = t2.AnswerID
GROUP BY t1.AnswerID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
SELECT * FROM AnswerItems
where ItemID in (1,2)
group by Answerid having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: I think this query will return answers that have items 1 + 2 (+ other items). I mean that this query will return an answer that have items 1+2+3 or 1+2+4 Right?

Comment: this query will return answers that have items 1 and 2 -- this Ok, but will also return answers that have items 1, 2 and 3 OR 1, 2 and 4 OR 1,2 and 6 -- we need to get answers that don't have items other than 1 and 2

Comment: @MegamindSaiko can you create example of what you meant in sql fiddle?

Comment: example in the question above